# Hadith Of 70,000 people of jannah

Tags: aqidah

So you know the hadith of Abu Umamah Al-Bahili said:
“I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say: ‘My Lord has promised me that seventy thousand of my nation will enter Paradise without being brought to account or punished. With every thousand will be (another) seventy thousand, and three handfuls of my Lord, the Glorified.’”

In this hadith what does handful really mean? If this means that three handfuls that will be grasped by Allah isn't this limiting Allah? And how do be Comprehend The hadith that says allah will hold earth in his hand
Please help

Comment: I don't understand your confusion? The "three handfuls" refer to the giving and generosity of our Lord Subhanahu Wa Ta'la, as someone spreading or giving, while nothing is like our Lord. If you can read Arabic: https://dorar.net/hadith/sharh/75435